# Closing a channel from the receiver side: deadlock when accessing sync.Mutex from multiple goroutines

Tags: go, mutex, deadlock, channel

I'm trying to implement graceful **channel closing from receiver side**.

Yes, I'm aware that this violates the channel closing rule:

> ...[don't close a channel from the receiver side and don't close a channel if the channel has multiple concurrent senders.](http://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-channel-closing)

But I want to implement such logic. Unfortunately, I fail into deadlock issue in the number of cases: the application just hangs for the unlimited time, trying to lock same locked `Mutex` again.

So, I have 2 goroutines:

- one that will write into a channel and
- another that will receive data + will close channel from the receiver side.

My channel wrapped in the struct with `sync.Mutex` and `closed` boolean flag:

```
type Chan struct {
    sync.Mutex // can be replaced with deadlock.Mutex from "github.com/sasha-s/go-deadlock"
    data           chan int
    closed         bool
}
```

All `Send()`, `Close()`, `IsClosed()` operations on this struct are guarded with `Mutex` and to prevent duplicate locking have the *non-threadsafe method versions* (`send()`, `close()`, `isClosed()`).

The full source code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("Start")

    ch := New(0) // unbuffered channel to expose problem faster

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    // send data:
    go func(ch *Chan) {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            ch.Send(i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(ch)

    // receive data and close from receiver side:
    go func(ch *Chan) {
        for data := range ch.data {
            log.Printf("Received %d data", data)
            // Bad practice: I want to close the channel from receiver's side:
            if data > 50 {
                ch.Close()
                break
            }
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(ch)

    wg.Wait()
    log.Println("End")
}

type Chan struct {
    deadlock.Mutex //sync.Mutex
    data           chan int
    closed         bool
}

func New(size int) *Chan {
    defer func() {
        log.Printf("Channel was created")
    }()
    return &Chan{
        data: make(chan int, size),
    }
}

func (c *Chan) Send(data int) {
    c.Lock()
    c.send(data)
    c.Unlock()
}

func (c *Chan) Close() {
    c.Lock()
    c.close()
    c.Unlock()
}

func (c *Chan) IsClosed() bool {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    return c.isClosed()
}

// send is internal non-threadsafe api.
func (c *Chan) send(data int) {
    if !c.closed {
        c.data <- data
        log.Printf("Data %d was sent", data)
    }
}

// close is internal non-threadsafe api.
func (c *Chan) close() {
    if !c.closed {
        close(c.data)
        c.closed = true
        log.Println("Channel was closed")
    } else {
        log.Println("Channel was already closed")
    }
}

// isClosed is internal non-threadsafe api.
func (c *Chan) isClosed() bool {
    return c.closed
}
```

You can run this program in the [sandbox](https://goplay.space/#P5NYRPlvZBh).

On the local machine, in small number of runs, after 30 seconds the output will be (using `deadlock.Mutex` instead of `sync.Mutex`):

```
2018/04/01 11:26:22 Data 50 was sent
2018/04/01 11:26:22 Received 50 data
2018/04/01 11:26:22 Data 51 was sent
2018/04/01 11:26:22 Received 51 data
POTENTIAL DEADLOCK:
Previous place where the lock was grabbed
goroutine 35 lock 0xc42015a040
close-from-receiver-side/closeFromReceiverSideIsBadPractice.go:71 main.(*Chan).Send { c.Lock() } <<<<<
close-from-receiver-side/closeFromReceiverSideIsBadPractice.go:30 main.main.func1 { ch.Send(i) }

Have been trying to lock it again for more than 30s
goroutine 36 lock 0xc42015a040
close-from-receiver-side/closeFromReceiverSideIsBadPractice.go:77 main.(*Chan).Close { c.Lock() } <<<<<
close-from-receiver-side/closeFromReceiverSideIsBadPractice.go:44 main.main.func2 { ch.Close() }
```

Why this deadlock happened and how to fix this implementation to avoid deadlocks?

---

Closing the channel on the sender's side is not the answer. So, this is not the fix for my question: [Example of closing channel from sender side](https://goplay.space/#3oVCHXBDywu).

Comment: https://goplay.space/#ulKXV96MDe3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send grabs the lock, then attempts to sends data down the channel. This may happen just after the 50th receive operation. There will be no more receives, so `c.data <- data` blocks forever and consequently the Mutex is held forever.

For cancellation, use another channel (instead of the boolean) and a select statement in Send. You can also leverage [the context package](https://golang.org/pkg/context/).

Comment: Thank you, @Peter! Is it possible to fix this with `sync.Mutex`+`bool` ?

Comment: yes you can but then you have to protect the bool with another mutex and if you do that wrong you end up in the same position you are in now. It is much easier and cleaner to use a channel or a context as Peter suggested.

Comment: @skovtunenko, no. As I said in the answer, you have to unblock the send on the channel eventually. Protecting a channel with a Mutex makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as hard as you like: you have to close the channel from sender side.

You might be able to get it working without a complete lockdown but you will leak goroutines. The sender will block forever and cannot be shut down. If the receiver wants to trigger a shutdown it has to tell the sender to shut the channel down. How you could tell the sender to shut down:

- A boolean as you suggest (needs another mutex)
- A `stop`-channel that when closed signals the sender to close the data channel (cannot be closed multiple times)
- a `ctx.Context`: calling the `cancel()` function will signal the sender to stop. (Can be cancelled multiple times without worry)

(Only elaborating on Peters correct answer)